# Working with directories and Files

Tags: c#

How to enumerate hidden files /directories in C# 4.0

Basically I use

```
var directories = new DirectoryInfo(@"DirectoryName")
                .EnumerateDirectories()
                .Where(**What is the condition that should go here?**)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  [FileAttributes.Hidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx)

```
var Directories = new DirectoryInfo(@"DirectoryName")
                .EnumerateDirectories()
                .Where(x => x.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
                .Select(x => x.Name);
```